# How can I make a smithing table recipe that yields a named item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I am trying to make a datapack where you can combine a turtle shell and a netherite ingot in a smithing table to get a turtle shell with knockback resistance and armor toughness. I have figured out the whole smithing table situation, but I cannot get it to yield an item with attributes. Here is a snip of what it looks like in the smithing table and a snip of the code.
[image: What inside the smithing table currently looks like]

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:smithing",
  "base": {
    "item": "minecraft:turtle_helmet"
  },
  "addition": {
    "item": "minecraft:netherite_ingot"
  },
  "result": {
    "item": "minecraft:turtle_helmet"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Minecraft 1.14.4 allow NBT tags in crafting recipes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354981/does-minecraft-1-14-4-allow-nbt-tags-in-crafting-recipes)

Comment: also, it looks like you have an extra bracket in the `result` object

Comment: @ppery that says 1.14. I think this should either a) not be a duplicate, or if it is, then b) edit the other question so its more general

Comment: @ppery wait nvm this isnt a duplicate at all. this asks for a smithing table not a crafting table

Comment: The wiki is ambiguous as to what smithing actually does: "[TAG_Compound] result Item specifying the resulting type of the upgraded item." which indicates to me that you might be able to supply a complete item tag for the result.  This is completely different from all the other recipes.