# Custom recipes with item with custom NBT as output

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm trying to make custom recipes for a datapack and have found out how, but not how to change the output to anything but a basic item. I want to output a carrot_on_a_stick with the custom NBT data of `CustomModelData:1`.
Currently the recipe is just simply this as a test:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
  "pattern":
  [
    "   ",
    "###",
    "#  "
  ],
  "key":
  {
    "#":
    {
      "item": "minecraft:iron_ingot"
    }
  },
  "result":
  {
    "item": "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",
    "count": 1

  }
}
```

So I want to know where/how to add NBT or if it's just not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, the answer is no. Please see: [Does Minecraft allow NBT tags in crafting recipes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354981/does-minecraft-allow-nbt-tags-in-crafting-recipes)

Comment: I'm really starting to lean towards learning to make mods at this point... :/

Comment: Yeah I don't think its possible

Comment: @WickedGrinn You could use some of the commands-based workarounds